# JSON.NET parsing error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've following json string:

```
{
  "message": "Keine Nachricht mit der Id 55555 gefunden!",
  "exception": {
    "__className": "Exception"
  },
  "request": {
    "__className": "Zend_Controller_Request_Http"
  }
}
```

`JObject.Parse()` will throw me this error:

```
"Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: . Path '', line 1, position 153."
```

What is wrong this JSON string?

Comment: Are there any spaces or chars at the end of the json string?

Comment: There are control characters at the end. Sorry was my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It parses fine for me in Ruby.  The string (when it was one long line) is 152 characters so there may have been a character after that.

Answer (score 0):

The following application works:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x =
            @"{""message"": ""Keine Nachricht mit der Id 55555 gefunden!"",""exception"": {""__className"": ""Exception""},""request"": {""__className"": ""Zend_Controller_Request_Http""}}";

        var y = JObject.Parse(x);
    }
}
```

Check to make sure the string you think you're passing to Parse() indeed looks like the above string.